# Why app needs both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions to decode bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, permissions, bitmapfactory

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile return null` if only `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  permissions set. Why is it necessary to use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` it's needed only open bitmap (not modify)?

Comment: Its not necessary if you do not need to read/write storage . Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission. Just for instance if your app need to read sms then only you need `READ_SMS` permission same goes with all others .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessary to give these permissions for decoding bitmap. May be you was accessing Bitmap from external storage that's why its asking for permissions.

Here you can take deep overview of permissions.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Sharing your code will be beneficial to sort out issue quickly.